# ORA-12805: parallel query server died unexpectedly

Tags: database, oracle, oracle11g

We are getting below error frequently on one of our RAC instance. Because of the same error, the applicatin is getting hanged and causing problem.

```
Sat Aug 04 06:57:26 2012
IPC Send timeout detected.Sender: ospid 28201
Receiver: inst 1 binc 8 ospid 3537
GATHER_STATS_JOB encountered errors.  Check the trace file.
Errors in file /opt/oracle/db/diag/rdbms/mdspdb/mdspdb5/trace/mdspdb5_j001_28201.trc:
ORA-12805: parallel query server died unexpectedly
```

Again one more error which we are getting is as below:

```
Thu Aug 09 03:43:05 2012
IPC Send timeout detected.Sender: ospid 18645
Receiver: inst 1 binc 8 ospid 3537
GATHER_STATS_JOB encountered errors.  Check the trace file.
Errors in file /opt/oracle/db/diag/rdbms/mdspdb/mdspdb5/trace/mdspdb5_j002_18645.trc:
ORA-20011: Approximate NDV failed: ORA-12805: parallel query server died unexpectedly
```

The output from the trace file is:

```
Trace file /opt/oracle/db/diag/rdbms/mdspdb/mdspdb5/trace/mdspdb5_j001_22631.trc
Oracle Database 11g Enterprise Edition Release 11.1.0.7.0 - 64bit Production
With the Partitioning, Real Application Clusters, OLAP, Data Mining
and Real Application Testing options
ORACLE_HOME = /opt/oracle/db/product/11.1.0/db_1
System name:    Linux
Node name:  mdspdb05
Release:    2.6.16.46-0.12-smp
Version:    #1 SMP Thu May 17 14:00:09 UTC 2007
Machine:    x86_64
Instance name: mdspdb5
Redo thread mounted by this instance: 5
Oracle process number: 107
Unix process pid: 22631, image: oracle@mdspdb05 (J001)


*** 2012-08-15 03:43:12.742
*** SESSION ID:(486.34904) 2012-08-15 03:43:12.742
*** CLIENT ID:() 2012-08-15 03:43:12.742
*** SERVICE NAME:(SYS$USERS) 2012-08-15 03:43:12.742
*** MODULE NAME:(DBMS_SCHEDULER) 2012-08-15 03:43:12.742
*** ACTION NAME:(ORA$AT_OS_OPT_SY_40411) 2012-08-15 03:43:12.742

IPC Send timeout detected.Sender: ospid 22631
Receiver: inst 1 binc 8 ospid 3537
SKGXP: SKGXPCTX: 0x0x2abb52d24a38 ctx
SKGXP: 
SKGXP: WAIT HISTORY
SKGXP: Time(msec)    Wait Type   Return Code
SKGXP: ----------    ---------   ------------
SKGXP: 2501      NORMAL      TIMEDOUT
SKGXP: 0         NORMAL      TIMEDOUT
SKGXP: 0         NORMAL      TIMEDOUT
SKGXP: 2500      NORMAL      TIMEDOUT
SKGXP: 0         NORMAL      TIMEDOUT
SKGXP: 0         NORMAL      TIMEDOUT
SKGXP: 2503      NORMAL      TIMEDOUT
SKGXP: 0         NORMAL      TIMEDOUT
SKGXP: 0         NORMAL      TIMEDOUT
SKGXP: 2501      NORMAL      TIMEDOUT
SKGXP: 0         NORMAL      TIMEDOUT
SKGXP: 0         NORMAL      TIMEDOUT
SKGXP: 2503      NORMAL      TIMEDOUT
SKGXP: 0         NORMAL      TIMEDOUT
SKGXP: 0         NORMAL      TIMEDOUT
SKGXP: 2500      NORMAL      TIMEDOUT
SKGXP: wait delta 61 sec (61423 msec) ctx ts 0x79e31f last ts 0x79e31f
SKGXP: user cpu time since last wait 0 sec 0 ticks
SKGXP: system cpu time since last wait 0 sec 0 ticks
SKGXP: locked 1
SKGXP: blocked 25048
SKGXP: timed wait receives 15
SKGXP: admno 0x66859bfb admport:
SKGXP: SSKGXPT 0x52d2597c flags  sockno 18 IP 192.168.1.10 UDP 61826
SKGXP: context timestamp 0x79e31f
SKGXP: buffers queued on port 0x2abb53449f50
SKGXP: 
SKGXP:    Dumping Connection Handle Table
SKGXP:     sconno     accono   ertt  state   seq#   RcvPid   TotCreditsSKGXP:   sent rtrans   acks
SKGXP:     CNH Table Bucket: 0
SKGXP: 0x03a8c901 0x50790ec9 46982647250960 46982647250948 46982647284070 46982647267591 46982647250952SKGXP:    363d      1d  33126d
SKGXP:     CNH Table Bucket: 1
SKGXP: 0x03a8c902 0x051d84d8     16 46982647250948 46982647284112 46982647259415 46982647250952SKGXP:    405d      0d  33168d
SKGXP:     CNH Table Bucket: 2
SKGXP: 0x03a8c903 0x51d441b2     16 46982647250948 46982647284217 46982647258187 46982647250952SKGXP:    510d      0d  33273d
SKGXP:     CNH Table Bucket: 3
SKGXP: 0x03a8c904 0x7d38c1af     16 46982647250948 46982647283952 46982647267615 46982647250952SKGXP:    245d      0d  33008d
SKGXP:     CNH Table Bucket: 4
SKGXP: 0x03a8c905 0x22782e02     16 46982647250948 46982647284097 46982647283080 46982647250952SKGXP:    390d      0d  33153d
SKGXP:     CNH Table Bucket: 5
SKGXP: 0x03a8c906 0x19e5dbdb     16 46982647250948 46982647284141 46982647283122 46982647250952SKGXP:    434d      0d  33197d
SKGXP:     CNH Table Bucket: 6
SKGXP: 0x03a8c907 0x024222c8     16 46982647250948 46982647283839 46982647258304 46982647250952SKGXP:    132d      0d  32895d
SKGXP:     CNH Table Bucket: 7
SKGXP: 0x03a8c908 0x1f3d5569     16 46982647250948 46982647284073 46982647283097 46982647250952SKGXP:    366d      0d  33129d
SKGXP:     CNH Table Bucket: 8
SKGXP: 0x03a8c909 0x4b4e08b3     16 46982647250948 46982647283990 46982647267605 46982647250952SKGXP:    283d      1d  33046d
SKGXP:     CNH Table Bucket: 9
SKGXP: 0x03a8c90a 0x32e47d79     16 46982647250948 46982647283856 46982647258242 46982647250952SKGXP:    149d      0d  32912d
SKGXP:     CNH Table Bucket: 10
SKGXP: 0x03a8c90b 0x60420275     16 46982647250948 46982647283829 46982647259471 46982647250952SKGXP:    122d      0d  32885d
SKGXP:     CNH Table Bucket: 11
SKGXP: 0x03a8c90c 0x5521db22     16 46982647250948 46982647283834 46982647259493 46982647250952SKGXP:    127d      0d  32890d
SKGXP:     CNH Table Bucket: 12
SKGXP: 0x03a8c90d 0x1696da78     16 46982647250948 46982647283708 46982647254481 46982647250952SKGXP:      1d    373d      0d
SKGXP: slot 3 rqh=0x2abb52d2e0e8 seq=32763 len=2144 accno=0x1696da78 start TS=0x2f31c rt TS=0x79e56c X CNT=374
SKGXP: 
SKGXP:    Dumping Accept Handle Table
SKGXP:        ach     accono     sconno      admno  state     SndPid   seq#    rcv rtrans   acks    credits
Dumping KSXP Connection Handle: cnh: 0x2abb54b97098
Link in Component Context : 0x2abb52fc0c08 <- cnh -> 0x2abb52fc0c08
Link in Connection Cache  : 0x2abb53070050 <- cnh -> 0x2abb52f68158
Pending Async Sends       : First: 0x2abb52d2e030 Last 0x2abb52d2e030
Name: 
State: 1 ==> OPEN
Flags: 0x0  ==> 
Connect request handle: (nil)
Miners Canary         : (nil)
OSD Connection handle : 0x2abb55286938
Stats pointer         : 0x19ee7f470
System incarnation when connection was made: 78
Dumping Target id for cnh
vers: 1 type: (1 ==> KSXP_TRANSPORT_ID_SKGXPPID) inst: 1 ptid: 401 ukey: 8
Protocol Info: vendor: 1 proto: 2 maj: 3 min: 0
pnum: 91 ospid: 3537
p1_pad1: 0 p2_pad1: (nil)
pad2: 0 pad3: 0
Dumping SKGXP Port ID: 0x2abb54b97120
SKGXP: SKGXPID 0x2abb54b97120 
SKGXP: skgxp port number 0x25a32042 process id 3537
SKGXP: admin port id
SKGXP: SKGXPGPID 0x7fff596feb58
SKGXP:  Internet address 192.168.1.12
SKGXP:  UDP port number 28958
Dumping connection stats 0x19ee7f470
Dumping SKGXP Connection Handle: osd cnh: 0x2abb55286938
SKGXP: SKGXPCNH: 0x2abb55286938 SKGXPCON_OPEN (2) sconno 3a8c90d accono 1696da78 admno fd8255e
SKGXP:  Remote admin port
SKGXP: SSKGXPT 0x55286974 flags SSKGXPT_WRITE sockno 18 IP 192.168.1.12 UDP 28958
SKGXP:  Remote data port
SKGXP: SSKGXPT 0x55286a08 flags SSKGXPT_WRITE sockno 18 IP 192.168.1.12 UDP 29092
SKGXP:  no disconnect notification request handle
SKGXP:   next seqno 32764 credits 7 ertt 16 resends on con 488510

*** 2012-08-15 03:43:12.792
Submitting synchronized dump request [268435460]

*** 2012-08-15 03:43:14.796
kxfp_send_callback
        Send timed out to slave 0 inst 1 (qref 0x19e82bf88)
kxfpgsg 
        Error 12805 encountered

*** 2012-08-15 03:43:14.831
ORA-20011: Approximate NDV failed: ORA-12805: parallel query server died unexpectedly

*** 2012-08-15 03:43:14.831
GATHER_STATS_JOB: GATHER_TABLE_STATS('"IMUSE01"','"SUBSCRIBEINFO"','""', ...)
ORA-20011: Approximate NDV failed: ORA-12805: parallel query server died unexpectedly
```

Oracle Version: **Oracle 11.1.0.6.0 RAC**

Comment: Does the error always happen for the same table?  If so, maybe it's a data error similar to the one in ID 1195204.1 (on My Oracle Support).  Also, have you tried disabling incremental statistics for the relevant table(s)?  If you're using a lot of incremental statistics, have you ran into any problems running out of space on SYSAUX?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

This was a bug in Oracle RAC. We upgraded the version to Oracle 11.1.0.7

The problem is solved now